# Obliterating already integrated feature branch

Tags: perforce

I work in a team creating plenty of feature "stream task".

Even if we do delete the stream task after integration, the associated branch still exists in the depot and is somewhat cluttering various user interfaces.

I am tempted to ask the admin to obliterate them as we go along.

I have already read carefully : http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2565

However, the obliterate is always associated with the scary warning "please contact Perforce Support first". So before going down that path I would like to know what are the risks, except erasing the wrong branch.

1. What will happen to files that have been initially created in feature branches ? Will obliterating the original, transform the lazy copy into a full fledged file ?Since the lazy copy is in the mainline, will the oldest revision will now point to the on in the mainline ?
2. Will it interfere with the "interchange" command ? If I have 2 "dev" branch moving in parallel, I believe it will still work because I will be actually compare the "merge changelist" that won't be affected by the removal of the task branch ?
3. What happens if a file is renamed in feature branch ? Will I lose the full range of history and the 2 files will look "disconnected" ?
4. Is there any other risk I have not taken into account ?

Issue 3 is particularly dangerous, and could be a good reason to not go on with the plan.

I currently believe it is "safe" to obliterate an already integrated feature branch if 1 & 2 are true :

1. No move/add/delete has been done in the branch (this can be checked by fstat headaction property)
2. No subranch has been created from the branch (since we are using task stream this is enforced by default)

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if a file has been integrated elsewhere, obliterating only the file in the task stream is safe, and you will still have the file by its other name.

But, the record of the changes (add/edit/delete, rename, further branching, etc.) that occurred to the file in the task stream will indeed be removed if you obliterate the task stream's history of the file, and so the overall history can end up being confusing and harder to read.

Myself, I prefer to maintain the entire history of those files, but I understand the view that, in the abstract, more history is not always better history.

When you are done with your task stream, are you deleting the stream spec? This will cause the unmodified files from the task stream to disappear, leaving you with only the history of the files that were actually modified in the task stream, which is typically a much smaller set of files.

Comment: Yes, we already remove the "unchanged file" but after one or two months of moderate use we already have created 200 branches. This might not be enormous but I foresee some issues in a few years. So I would rather like to carefully prune the tree has we move along.

Comment: For the time being I'll probably remove all the branch where only some simple edits have been done, and will preserve any add/delete/rename to keep the overall history clean. That should allow me to remove some clutter while keeping the important pieces of history.